# show all posts of all users from firebase in single recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am planning to display all posts by all users from firebase into my single firebase recycler adapter.
Is it possible to show that? If yes, then can you describe me how to show that?

[image: [enter image description here]

Comment: The FirebaseUI adapters take a single reference or query, so this structure seems unideal for display the posts across all users. If you want to show a list of posts from all users, store that in the database.

Comment: Your data structure also violates some of Firebase's recommendations: by putting the posts for each user under the profile data for each user, you'll be required to read all posts if you want to show a list of user profiles.